# Effective Java: ensureCapacity() method

Tags: java

In the book Bloch wrote:

```
class Stack{
    private Object[] elements;

    // Code omitted

    public void push(Object e) {
        ensureCapacity();
        elements[size++] = e;
    }

    // Ensure space for at least one more element
    private void ensureCapacity() {
        if (elements.length==size) {
            elements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, 2*size + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Why did he use

> 2*size+1

to increment size of the array by 1?

Comment: Because he didn't want to *(just)* increase the size by 1???? Your question is a bit out of context.

Comment: Without seeing the surrounding code or any of his text, how do you think we're supposed to provide an intelligent answer?

Comment: Please post any relevant information - I had to see the page in Google Books to see what you were even talking about.

Comment: I guess, I always have to make sure that I am on a desktop computer to make a SO post, because using SO's mobile app to type in all the code and then format it properly will take a lot of time. I better uninstall the app, as it only gets me downvotes :)

Answer (score 2):

He is doubling the size of the stack when it becomes full.

0 -> 2*0+1 = 1

1 -> 1*2+1 = 3

3 -> 3*2+1 = 7

7 -> 7*2+1 = 15

This is how dynamic arrays function. By doubling every time you hit the maximum capacity, you reduce the big Oh complexity of copying over the entire array when you run out of space.

The time it takes to store n elements in the data structure is O(2n) which is really O(n) which is the same complexity as a fixed size array which does not have to deal with copying cost.

If you would like to see a proof and intuitive explanation of this wonderful idea, watch this [lecture by Prof. Skiena from the 41 minute mark](https://youtu.be/xoeBZNailFc?t=41m17s).

Comment: But he said he was just ensuring that the array could contain "one more element"

Comment: If he copied over the entire array every time he inserted a new element, it would be a horribly slow and impractical algorithm. Each insertion would take O(n) time and so to insert n elements it would take O(n²) time.

Answer (score 0):

Because otherwise you would need to handle the empty case specially: if you always double the capacity, going from empty array to 1-element array is impossible. Of course, you could do "if size is `0`, then `1`; else `2 * size`"; but `2 * size + 1` handles it without a conditional (`0` to `1`, `1` to `3`, `3` to `7`...). The clue can be found in the comment:

```
/**
 * Ensure space for at least one more element, roughly
 * doubling the capacity each time the array needs to grow.
 */
```

("at least one more element", whatever `size` is).

Answer (score 0):

The "old objects" (the elements in the array) get copied into the new array in this line:

**elements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, 2 * size + 1);**
As for the old elements array, it'll eventually get garbage collected, because there are no more references pointing to it.